# Android KeyStore: While the device is locked, can background processes still access keys?

Tags: keystore, android-keystore, keystore-access

Basically whats going on is I want to encrypt/decrypt some session tokens (just a string) before/after storing them. However I've read that the Android KeyStore is locked and unaccessible while the device is locked, but I still need to be able to access the KeyStore even while the device is locked. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here?